# Poor JUnit test using springframework has fragile Thread.sleep() calls. How to fix?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-test

I have recently joined a group with some severe JUnit testing issues. One problem is an 8 minute long test! The test has several sections; each makes calls to org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent()
followed by Thread.sleep() of various amounts of time, then tests conditions.

There are several obvious problems with this approach, the timing of the Thread.sleep() calls is fragile:

- tests occasionally fail on busy machines; and
- tests take far too long when they do not fail.

Is the pool upon which these events are handled accessible for testing and is there a call to see if the event cascade has quiesced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the default `applicationEventMulticaster` by adding this bean id to your application context.

Instead of the default `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster`, you could set a TaskExecutor on this bean to perform the event publishing asynchronously in multiple threads.

Or you could implement your own multicaster, which prints out which event listener took so long or was blocking, for how long and on which events. That could help you to track down the real problem of the 8-Minute-Testcase.

Interestingly, the JavaDoc of the SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster, which is used by default by Spring when you are using ApplicationContext, states the following:

> By default, all listeners are invoked in the calling thread. **This allows the danger of a rogue listener blocking the entire application**, but adds minimal overhead. Specify an alternative TaskExecutor to have listeners executed in different threads, for example from a thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

Worth mentioning is that test code that actually calls external services are integration tests and not unit tests. If you're truly unit testing here you should replace those calls with mocks. That way you can better control the values returned to your business logic and test for specific conditions. Also, as you've seen, this all but eliminates false positives due to external (non-code) situations. Obviously these tests aren't failing, the facility they expect to use is.

Comment: +1 I think this is the answer to the underlying question. Mock out the externals and the tests will run faster.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not a Unit test, it is an integration test. Can anyone help with my questions about speeding up this integration test. (I did not write it. I just want it fast.)

Answer (score 0):

I (intentionally) avoid Spring so I'm not sure I can help with the specifics but just looking at the sleep issue, you can use something like `WaitFor` in tempus-fugit (shameless plug) to poll for a `Condition` rather than "sleep and hope". It's not ideal and usually a change in the way you test (as suggested before) is preferable but it does mean you get finer grained "waits" which are more likely to avoid race-conditions / flaky tests and generally speed up the test.

See the project's [documentation](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/time/waiting/) for details and post back if you find it useful!